# Taxonomy terms not showing up in drupal 6

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms, nodes, updating

I updated the drupal 6 site via drush, moved all of the modules into the correct places, but the taxonomy terms saved using the form attached to the content type does not appear on the node afterwards.

Comment: Do the terms you chose show up in the node/edit form of a previously saved node?  That will help determine whether it is just a display issue or a deeper problem with association.

Comment: The great folks at Drupassist helped me realize it was the theme-specific settings. This specific theme acquia marina has an option to turn on and off specific taxonomy. This menu path is also documented in Drupal in 24 Hours.